# For loop / over written variable

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

```
/*
  Program to calculate trip and plan flights
*/
#define TRIP 6
#define NUMLEG 10 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int input_trip(void);
int input_leg(int travel_leg[NUMLEG], int index);
char input_travel_type(char leg_type[TRIP][NUMLEG], int n, int index, int leg_num);
int main(void)
{ 
  int  row, col, trip_num, index, travel_leg[NUMLEG], leg_num, n; 
  char leg_type[TRIP][NUMLEG];
  trip_num = input_trip();
  for (index =0; index < trip_num; index++)
    { 
      leg_num = input_leg(travel_leg,index);

      printf("At Trip Number:%d\n", index);
      printf("Number of legs %d\n", leg_num );

      printf("A Airplane\n");
      printf("R Train and rail travel\n");
      printf("B Bus\n");
      printf("C Car\n");
      printf("F Ferry\n");
      printf("S Cruise ship\n");
      printf("M Motorcycle\n");
      printf("Y Bicycle\n");
      printf("T Boat other than a ferry or cruise ship\n");
      printf("D Dirigible\n");
      printf("O Other\n");
      printf("NOTE!!:Please using capital letters (case sensitive).\n");

      for (n = 0; n < leg_num; n ++)
    {
      printf("At leg Number%d\n", n);
      input_travel_type(leg_type, n, index, leg_num);
    }
    }

  for (index = 0; index < trip_num; index++)
    {
      printf("Trip#:%d Num_leg:%d ", index+1, travel_leg[index]);
      for (n = 0;  n < leg_num ; n++)
    printf("Leg_type(#%d):%c ",n+1, leg_type[index][n]);
      printf("\n");

    }

  return 0;
}

int input_trip(void)
{
  int trip_num;

  printf("Please enter the number of trips:");
  scanf("%d", &trip_num);
  // if( (trip_num <= TRIP) && (trip_num >= 3))
  if( (trip_num <= TRIP) && (trip_num >=1) ) 
    {
      return trip_num;
    }


  else 
    {
      while ((trip_num < 1) || ( trip_num > TRIP))
    {
      printf("Invalid number of trip. (Min of 3 trips and Max 6 trips).\n");  /*input number of trips*/
      printf("Please enter the number of trips:");
      scanf("%d", &trip_num);
      if( (trip_num <= TRIP) && (trip_num >= 1))
        {
          return trip_num;
        }
    }

    } 
}
int input_leg(int travel_leg[NUMLEG], int index)
{
  int leg_num, i;
  char travel_type, checkA, A, R, B, C, F, S, M, Y, T, D, O;

  printf("Please enter the number of legs in your trip:");
  scanf("%d", &leg_num);
  if ( (leg_num <= NUMLEG) && (leg_num > 0) )
    {    
      travel_leg[index]=leg_num;
      return leg_num;
    }
  else 
    {
      while ( (leg_num < 0) || (leg_num > NUMLEG))
    {
      printf("Invalid number of legs(min 1 and max 10 legs).\n");
      printf("Please enter the number of legs in your trip:");
      scanf("%d", &leg_num);
      if ( (leg_num <= NUMLEG) && (leg_num > 0) )
        {
          travel_leg[index]=leg_num;
          return leg_num;
        }
    }
    }
}

char input_travel_type(char leg_type[TRIP][NUMLEG], int n, int index, int leg_num)
{
  char travel_type, checkA;
  printf("Please enter the leg type for leg#%d:", n+1);
  scanf("%c", &travel_type);
  checkA = ( (travel_type == 'A') || (travel_type == 'R') || (travel_type == 'B') || 
         (travel_type == 'C') || (travel_type == 'F') || (travel_type == 'S') ||
         (travel_type == 'M') || (travel_type == 'Y') || (travel_type == 'T') ||
         (travel_type == 'D') || (travel_type == '0') );

  if (checkA == 1)
    {
      leg_type[index][n]=travel_type;
    }
  else 
    {
      while (checkA != 1)
    {
      printf("Please enter the leg type for leg#%d:", n+1);
      scanf("%c", &travel_type);
      checkA = ( (travel_type == 'A') || (travel_type == 'R') || (travel_type == 'B') || 
             (travel_type == 'C') || (travel_type == 'F') || (travel_type == 'S') ||
             (travel_type == 'M') || (travel_type == 'Y') || (travel_type == 'T') ||
             (travel_type == 'D') || (travel_type == '0') );

      if (checkA == 1)
        leg_type[index][n]=travel_type;
    }
    }
}
```

(I ask this question a while back but my code was too messy so I re-wrote it in functions so it was easier to read)

The problem I'm having is that my leg_num is getting over written every time I step out of the loop, so when I try to print out in the printf the last leg_num I put in is the number that is being use at:

for (n = 0;  n < leg_num ; n++)  the 2nd one in the printing loop

**EDITED**

So when I put in 2 trips  trip# 1 has 3 legs trip# 2 has 2 legs when it runs through the printing loops it will only print 2 legs for each trip.

```
Trip#:1 Num_leg:3 Leg_type(#1):C Leg_type(#2):B 
Trip#:2 Num_leg:2 Leg_type(#1):A Leg_type(#2):R 

Trip#:1 Num_leg:1 Leg_type(#1):S Leg_type(#2): 
Trip#:2 Num_leg:2 Leg_type(#1):F Leg_type(#2):S
```

Everything else works fine because I put printf statements along the way to check if that was the issue but it wasn't. I was thinking of saving the leg_num into a array and using that but not sure how to do it, plus the fact that this is part of a homework and our professor is restricting almost everything but the basic loops simple arrays.

Comment: which for (n = 0; n < leg_num ; n++)? the first or the second?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. "when I try to print [...] the last leg_num". leg_num seems to be read in input_leg function, and then remains constant?

Comment: oh I edited and put a example a little below it

Comment: your code is very difficult to understand.. first of all if you declare that a function will return something then it should return something.. in almost all function you're returning values inside if statements...so there might be cases when your function is not returning anything at all

Comment: You still have this `char [...] A, R, B, C, F, S, M, Y, T, D, O;` bunch of pointless variables that you never use.

Comment: it might be due to memory leakage... cause you're using leg_num name as instance variables in other functions tooo... just clean up your code... remove extra/unused vars.. Make sure that you're not setting leg_num in any other function.

Comment: yea think I'll redo some variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  printf("Trip#:%d Num_leg:%d ", index+1, travel_leg[index]);
  for (n = 0;  n < leg_num ; n++)
```

Change to

```
  printf("Trip#:%d Num_leg:%d ", index+1, travel_leg[index]);
  for (n = 0;  n < travel_leg[index] ; n++)
```

Comment: ah so instead of using another variable I just had to use the array ._.